# Writing the exists function correctly in a recursive way

Tags: haskell, recursion

How to fix this `exists'` function so that it works as required?

Tests whether any element of a list satisfies a given condition.

```
exists' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool

exists' p [] = False
exists' p (x:xs)
   | p == x = True
   | otherwise = exists' p xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Just checking the function over the value on the ward:

```
exists' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
exists' _ [] = False
exists' f (x:xs)
   | f x       = True
   | otherwise = exists' f xs
```

`f` is of type `(a -> bool)`, `x` is of type `a` ergo `f a` will return a bool, if it evaluates to True you just "return" True too, otherwise you make the recursive call as you were doing.

Comment: Thanks. Help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As [@DanielSanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44155668/67579) said in his answer, the problem is that you write `p == x` instead of `p x` so instead of calling the predicate on the head of the list, you check if the predicate is *equal* to the head of the list. As a result, `x` should also be of type `a -> Bool` (or `p` of type `a`) and the type of `p` and `x` should by an instance of the `Eq` class.

You can make the code a bit more elegant like:

```
exists' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
exists' _ [] = False
exists' p (x:xs) = p x || exists' p xs
```

Since now it reads *syntactically*: *there exists an element in a list that satisfies the given predicate given the list is not empty and the predicate is true for the head of the list, **or** such element exists in the remainder of the list*".

Finally we can also avoid passing the predicate in the recursive calls, by using a `where` clause, like:

```
exists' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
exists' p = helper
    where helper [] = False
          helper (x:xs) = p x || helper xs
```

Note that you do not have to write `exists'` yourself. There is the `any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool` function that is semantically equivalent.